# JQuery toggle() function hide link when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Wrote this JQuery code but I thought the questions (#question1 and #question2) would be hidden when they are clicked and #answer1 and 2 would be revealed. Hence 'toggle()' Does anyone have a suggestion of the best way I could do this so that neither is visible at the same time - if the question is clicked then the answer is revealed and the question is not displayed. I am not bothered about it going back (e.g when the answer is clicked it swaps again)

```
$(function(){
    $('#question1').live('click',function(){
      event.preventDefault();
        $('#answer1').toggle();
    });
});
$(function(){
    $('#question2').live('click',function(){
      event.preventDefault();
        $('#answer2').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: live has been deprecated and removed from jQuery for many many versions now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code which will work with any number of questions :

HTML:

```
<div class="question-container" id="question1">
    <p class="question">The question 1 </p>
    <p class="answer hide">The anwser 1</p>
</div>

<div class="question-container" id="question2">
    <p class="question">The question 2</p>
    <p class="answer hide">The anwser 2</p>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

JS :

```
$(function(){
     $('.question-container').on('click',function(pEvent){
        $(this).children('.answer').toggleClass('hide');
        $(this).children('.question').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kyo9jahw/3/